# Prove that $f $ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, 
$f(x)=f(x^2) $ prove that $f$ is constant.

"please give me hints not answer. thanks a lot. :):):):):)"

Comment: Try to draw the graph of it. :)

Comment: i tried, but it's not specific function. how can you draw it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, $f(x)=f(x^2)=f((-x)^2)=f(-x)$, so we only need to consider $x\ge0$.
Conversely, $f(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$.  If $f(x)\ne f(y)$, then take repeated square-roots of $x$ and $y$.  Look at the continuity of $f(x)$ near $x=1$.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: Let $x_0=x,x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}}$, $\lim x_n=1$, so $f(1)=\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$ by continuity, and also $f(1)=f(y)$

Comment: yes, absolutely yes. great thanks

Comment: I think we need to look at $x \geq 1$ and $0 \leq x < 1$ separately, as $x^{1/2^n}$ behaves differently in those two regions.

Comment: Hmm, yes $x=0$ is a special case, but I think it is the only one.  Then by continuity it must equal all the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Let $|x| < 1$. Then $x^{2^n} \to 0$ so $f(x^{2^n}) \to f(0).$  But all of the $f(x^{2^n})$ are all equal, so $f(x) = f(0)$.  Now you know that $f$ is constant on $(-1,1)$.  Can you go the rest of the way?